Resolving the "Could not find com.kezong:fat-aar:1.2.15" Error
When I tried to build an android project with gradle dependencies, building failed with "Could not find com.kezong:fat-aar:1.2.15" error. How can I resolve the issue?
I tried to find the dependency plugin in google but failed to find it.

The library that you have mentioned has not been maintained in several years. You can also see a disclaimer in the GitHub repository, where the owner has stated that:

I am no longer engaged in research and development, so the project
will not be updated and maintained. You can try to use the following
steps to reference the remote plugin. If it doesn't work on the new
version of gradle, you can fork or download this project to modify it,
the code of this project is not very complex.

You have written that you are using version 1.2.15, which was probably hosted in JCenter. The newest version is 1.3.8, which is hosted on mavenCentral, so you can try upgrading to that.
Note that the Fat AAR format is not something Google is supporting officially so there could still be issues with this dependency.

Version 1.2.15 of the library is at Maven Central. It's a configuration or network error.
